# error:conversion from 'QFont' to non-scalar type 'QFontMetricsF' requested-Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning from *C++ Programming with Qt*.  One of practice in Painter'chapter relative to diagram.

Here is my code:

```
#include <QFont>
#include<QFontMetricsF>
QRectF Node::outlineRect() const
{
    const int Padding = 8;
    QFontMetricsF metrics = qApp->font();
    QRectF rect = metrics.boundingRect(myText);
    rect.adjust(-Padding, -Padding, +Padding, +Padding);
    rect.translate(-rect.center());
    return rect;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following expression is uses [copy-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization):

```
QFontMetricsF metrics = qApp->font();
```

[copy-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) requires an implicit conversion from `QFont` to `QFontMetricsF`, but `QFontMetricsF`'s constructor that takes `QFont` is explicit. That's why you have to use [direct-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) (`()` or `{}`):

```
QFontMetricsF metrics(qApp->font());
QFontMetricsF metrics{qApp->font()};
```